# Is there a standalone community website application which one can easily populate with a Ning content dump?

Tags: ning

Ning [provides a structured content dump](http://help.ning.com/cgi-bin/ning.cfg/php/enduser/std_adp.php?p_faqid=3772) of Ning sites when requested.  I was wondering whether a) the schema for this dump is publically specified and b) any open-source web applications can use such a dump to populate a community website.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, if dump format is not yet published, it certainly will be by the time when networks are asked to start paying, and there will be flow of requests. I don't know details of format, but I would expect it to be in JSON or possibly in XML (maybe both alternatives are given).

Given that there may be a few networks who want to do, I would bet on tools being built by some network creators. Activity on creator network is quite high, and people seem helpful, so you could try asking this question there (if you haven't already).